# Protecting Excel worksheets - Impossible?

Tags: excel, vba, security, passwords, ms-office

I'm trying to share an Excel workbook, but with limited access to only a couple of visible sheets. This have proven to be much harder than first anticipated due to security loopholes with Excel and password protection of worksheets.

My problem arises due to some hidden sheets that needs to stay hidden and the contents inaccessible, but are required for calculations were the result is shown in the visible sheets.

So far I have tried to "super hide" the sheets in the VBA window and lock the VBA project. The idea is that the user then can't unhide the "super hidden" sheets without the VBA project password.
I have tried to add additional VBA code to counter certain "attacks", but I keep coming back to a known flaw that circumvents all my efforts:

Step 1:
Save or make sure that the Excel workbook is saved as .xlsx or .xlsm

Step 2:
Run the following code from a different workbook or your personal.xlsb that removes passwords from sheets and structure protection
(I would have linked to the post where I found the code, but I can't find it right now...).

```
Sub RemoveProtection()

Dim dialogBox As FileDialog
Dim sourceFullName As String
Dim sourceFilePath As String
Dim SourceFileName As String
Dim sourceFileType As String
Dim newFileName As Variant
Dim tempFileName As String
Dim zipFilePath As Variant
Dim oApp As Object
Dim FSO As Object
Dim xmlSheetFile As String
Dim xmlFile As Integer
Dim xmlFileContent As String
Dim xmlStartProtectionCode As Double
Dim xmlEndProtectionCode As Double
Dim xmlProtectionString As String

'Open dialog box to select a file
Set dialogBox = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
dialogBox.AllowMultiSelect = False
dialogBox.Title = "Select file to remove protection from"

If dialogBox.show = -1 Then
    sourceFullName = dialogBox.SelectedItems(1)
Else
    Exit Sub
End If

'Get folder path, file type and file name from the sourceFullName
sourceFilePath = Left(sourceFullName, InStrRev(sourceFullName, "\"))
sourceFileType = Mid(sourceFullName, InStrRev(sourceFullName, ".") + 1)
SourceFileName = Mid(sourceFullName, Len(sourceFilePath) + 1)
SourceFileName = Left(SourceFileName, InStrRev(SourceFileName, ".") - 1)

'Use the date and time to create a unique file name
tempFileName = "Temp" & Format(Now, " dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")

'Copy and rename original file to a zip file with a unique name
newFileName = sourceFilePath & tempFileName & ".zip"
On Error Resume Next
FileCopy sourceFullName, newFileName

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Unable to copy " & sourceFullName & vbNewLine _
        & "Check the file is closed and try again"
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0

'Create folder to unzip to
zipFilePath = sourceFilePath & tempFileName & "\"
MkDir zipFilePath

'Extract the files into the newly created folder
Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
oApp.Namespace(zipFilePath).CopyHere oApp.Namespace(newFileName).Items

'loop through each file in the \xl\worksheets folder of the unzipped file
xmlSheetFile = Dir(zipFilePath & "\xl\worksheets\*.xml*")
Do While xmlSheetFile <> ""

    'Read text of the file to a variable
    xmlFile = FreeFile
    Open zipFilePath & "xl\worksheets\" & xmlSheetFile For Input As xmlFile
    xmlFileContent = Input(LOF(xmlFile), xmlFile)
    Close xmlFile

    'Manipulate the text in the file
    xmlStartProtectionCode = 0
    xmlStartProtectionCode = InStr(1, xmlFileContent, "<sheetProtection")

    If xmlStartProtectionCode > 0 Then

        xmlEndProtectionCode = InStr(xmlStartProtectionCode, _
            xmlFileContent, "/>") + 2 '"/>" is 2 characters long
        xmlProtectionString = Mid(xmlFileContent, xmlStartProtectionCode, _
            xmlEndProtectionCode - xmlStartProtectionCode)
        xmlFileContent = Replace(xmlFileContent, xmlProtectionString, "")

    End If

    'Output the text of the variable to the file
    xmlFile = FreeFile
    Open zipFilePath & "xl\worksheets\" & xmlSheetFile For Output As xmlFile
    Print #xmlFile, xmlFileContent
    Close xmlFile

    'Loop to next xmlFile in directory
    xmlSheetFile = Dir

Loop

'Read text of the xl\workbook.xml file to a variable
xmlFile = FreeFile
Open zipFilePath & "xl\workbook.xml" For Input As xmlFile
xmlFileContent = Input(LOF(xmlFile), xmlFile)
Close xmlFile

'Manipulate the text in the file to remove the workbook protection
xmlStartProtectionCode = 0
xmlStartProtectionCode = InStr(1, xmlFileContent, "<workbookProtection")
If xmlStartProtectionCode > 0 Then

    xmlEndProtectionCode = InStr(xmlStartProtectionCode, _
        xmlFileContent, "/>") + 2 ''"/>" is 2 characters long
    xmlProtectionString = Mid(xmlFileContent, xmlStartProtectionCode, _
        xmlEndProtectionCode - xmlStartProtectionCode)
    xmlFileContent = Replace(xmlFileContent, xmlProtectionString, "")

End If

'Manipulate the text in the file to remove the modify password
xmlStartProtectionCode = 0
xmlStartProtectionCode = InStr(1, xmlFileContent, "<fileSharing")
If xmlStartProtectionCode > 0 Then

    xmlEndProtectionCode = InStr(xmlStartProtectionCode, xmlFileContent, _
        "/>") + 2 ''"/>" is 2 characters long
    xmlProtectionString = Mid(xmlFileContent, xmlStartProtectionCode, _
        xmlEndProtectionCode - xmlStartProtectionCode)
    xmlFileContent = Replace(xmlFileContent, xmlProtectionString, "")

End If

'Output the text of the variable to the file
xmlFile = FreeFile
Open zipFilePath & "xl\workbook.xml" & xmlSheetFile For Output As xmlFile
Print #xmlFile, xmlFileContent
Close xmlFile

'Create empty Zip File
Open sourceFilePath & tempFileName & ".zip" For Output As #1
Print #1, Chr$(80) & Chr$(75) & Chr$(5) & Chr$(6) & String(18, 0)
Close #1

'Move files into the zip file
oApp.Namespace(sourceFilePath & tempFileName & ".zip").CopyHere _
oApp.Namespace(zipFilePath).Items
'Keep script waiting until Compressing is done
On Error Resume Next
Do Until oApp.Namespace(sourceFilePath & tempFileName & ".zip").Items.count = _
    oApp.Namespace(zipFilePath).Items.count
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
Loop
On Error GoTo 0

'Delete the files & folders created during the sub
Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
FSO.deletefolder sourceFilePath & tempFileName

'Rename the final file back to an xlsx file
Name sourceFilePath & tempFileName & ".zip" As sourceFilePath & SourceFileName _
& "_" & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss") & "." & sourceFileType

'Show message box
MsgBox "The workbook and worksheet protection passwords have been removed.", _
vbInformation + vbOKOnly, Title:="Password protection"

End Sub
```

Step 3:
Run the following code to unhide all sheets

```
Sub UnhideAllSheets()

For Each Worksheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        Worksheet.Visible = -1
Next Worksheet

End Sub
```

The workbook is now clean of passwords on sheets and structure protection, and any "counter" VBA code is gone by saving the workbook as a .xlsx file.

I have thought about adding a user-defined function that checks if the extension of the workbook file is ".xlsb". The function would return "1" if the extension is ".xlsb" and then multiplying it on something important. This would cause the calculations to fail if the workbook is saved as something else, or if the VBA project is entirely removed to saving as .xlsx.
However, I do not like this approach as I don't think it is a long-term solution...

My question is therefore:
Is there a way to securely share an Excel workbook with only access to a couple of sheets without risking the user can access hidden sheets and/or unwanted contents?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no perfectly safe way to protect an excel workbook/worksheet. One way could be to encode the data so that even if the content is unhidden it would be unexploitable without the decoding function.

Comment: Hi Vincent G,

Interesting idea - How do you purpose to do that? Like a SHA256 function in excel?

Comment: I think the general takeaway of this question is that you can *never* assume that Excel is secure.

Comment: That is also what I have concluded so far - Sadly....

Answer (score 0):

In the VBE you can change the `Visible` property of a specific sheet to `xlSheetVeryHidden`.

[image]

This will remove it from the front end completely.

You can then add a password to protect the VBA project in the VBE to prevent a user from changing that property (if they even know about it).

[image]

Additionally, you will still be able to access these sheets with your VBA code.

**EDIT:**

What I also add to the above is a password to the specific sheet, as normal. But also a custom `UserForm` the `UserForm` gets triggered on the `Worksheet_Activate` event if they had to unhide it. If they enter the incorrect password or close the `UserForm` the sheet gets hidden away again. You can add all sorts to this event handler such as reprotect the worksheet, reprotect the project, protect the workbook with an encrypted password and close the workbook as a "breach" in security.

The possibilities are endless. Not an exact prevention, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: I think the 3rd paragraph of the question explain that he already did that.

Comment: @VincentG I have added some more too it. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Hi Dean,

I have also tried this, but it fails in the aspect of saving the file as a .xlsx (Which removes to VBA project with the counter code) .

If you save your workbook as an .xlsx file and run step 2 and 3, your worksheets will be visible and unprotected by by password and your VBA will be gone...